# VBA - format cell in excel

Tags: regex

I am writing a code and I want my output that is date to display in a specific format. How can i do it.?

I am writing my code in VBA. excel

I have tried doing this.

```
mystring = Range(x).Offset(0, p).Value = DateAdd("m", p, ActiveCell.Value)
```

output = Format(mystring, dd - mm - yyy)

Comment: Your code may be incorrect.  Note that mystring will evaluate to a boolean, not a date.  The 2nd argument for the Format function should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

It should be composed like:

```
Format(mystring, "dd-mm-yy")
```

the year is either `two` or `four` digits, ***not*** three.